# Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect (Permission denied)

Tags: php, linux

На Linux-машине установлены Apache и PHP.

В стороннем (заведомо исправном) PHP-коде есть обращение через сокет к внешнему сервису. Сервис с того хоста, где запущен PHP, доступен (можно, например, пощупать его телнетом), но PHP не может до него достучаться:

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to example.net:43 (Permission denied)

Другие хосты/порты также недоступны.

`allow_url_fopen` в `php.ini` разрешён.

Посмотрел `tcpdump`ом - при выполнении проблемного PHP кода никакой трафик в сторону искомого хоста вообще не вылетает.

Файрвол отключен.

Куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Проблема](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-connect.php#85795) может быть в SElinux, который контролирует доступ к сети различных приложений.

Проверка, включен ли SELinux:

```
/usr/sbin/sestatus -v
```

Разрешить доступ к сети:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

или так:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Если команда не применяется, надо попробовать выполнить её при остановленном демоне апача. После её успешного выполнения и запуска апача внешние коннекты через сокеты в PHP заработают.